# SSH Command PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ssh

I have this script:

Can script read 'commands' from comenzi.txt?

in comenzi .txt I have eg:

```
cd\
cd C:\Program Files\Apps
WS.exe update driver
SL.exe uninstall -f
cd\
cd C:\Program Files\Apps2
AB.exe stop service
AB.exe start service
```

```
    $entry = Get-Content -Path .\hostsss.txt
    $User = "user"
    $Password = "Pass"
    $Command = get command from comenzi.txt line by line

    $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
    $Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($User, $secpasswd)

Get-SSHTrustedHost | Remove-SSHTrustedHost

$SessionID = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $entry -Credential $Credentials -AcceptKey:$true

Invoke-SSHCommand -Index $sessionid.sessionid -Command $Command
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: It appears that the invoke-SSHCommand only accepts a single command "line" so if you are trying to  put many of them together; assuming you are using bash. Look at this article for how to put many Bash commands on one line:https:// stackoverflow.com/questions/5130847/running-multiple-commands-in-one-line-in-shell

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is you are using the Posh-SSH module, available [here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Posh-SSH/3.0.0-alpha) and documented further [here](https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/07/03/posh-ssh-open-source-ssh-powershell-module/). If correct, the latter document shows you can separate discrete commands by a semicolon.

Some code to join the data from comenzi.txt and form the `-Command` argument:

```
$Command = (Get-Content comenzi.txt) -join "; "
```

I presume the semicolon delimiter is a function of bash so this should work. Moreover, the previous comment notes the potential use of the `&&` operator. By description that seems to be equivalent to PowerShell 7's pipeline chain operator.  If that functionality is desired you can do the `-join` on that string to created `$Command`:

```
$Command = (Get-Content comenzi.txt) -join " && "
```

Comment: OpenSSH with Posh SSH module PS

Comment: That does look like the module I was asking about. I modified the answer a bit, but I think you should try the suggestion.  Let's see what happens...

Comment: ```
Host       : 10.21.1.1
Output     : {}
ExitStatus : 1
```
Commands does't run.